# Mounting failed - invalid argument

Tags: lvm, raspberry-pi, kali-linux, btrfs, luks

I've setup a Kali Linux installation on an SD card and created an encrypted LUKS partition with a LVM logical volume inside of it, then created a BTRFS filesystem inside. *Almost* everything works, but boot fails after decrypting the LUKS volume succeeds. Logs:

```
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scrypts/local-top ... [ 8.655803] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.28.0-ioctl (2014-09-17) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[ 8.689182] random: lvm urandom read with 113 bits of entropy available
  Volume group "pi" not found
  Skipping volume group pi
Unable to find LVM volume pi/root
Unlocking the disk /dev/mmcblk0p2 (picrypt)
Enter passphrase:
Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while...
  Found volume group "pi" using metadata type lvm2
  ffff0000-ffff1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0    [vectors]: mlock failed: Cannot allocate memory
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "pi" now active
  ffff0000-ffff1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0    [vectors]: munlock failed: Cannot allocate memory
cryptsetup: picrypt set up successfully
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... done.
mount: mounting /dev/mapper/pi-root on /root failed: Invalid argument
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... mount: mounting /de on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
done.
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
modprobe: module i8042 not found in modules.dep
modprobe: module atkbd not found in modules.dep
modprobe: module ehci-pci not found in modules.dep
modprobe: module ehci-orion not found in modules.dep
modprobe: module ehci-hcd not found in modules.dep
modprobe: module uhci-hcd not found in modules.dep
modprobe: module ohci-hcd not found in modules.dep

BusyBox v1.20.2 (Debian 1:1.20.0-7) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

/bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
```

It seems to fail to be able to mount my root filesystem. In the initramfs, I can actually mount the BTRFS partition just fine using all the options given in fstab. It seems to fail initially, for some strange reason that I can't diagnose.

In the initramfs, running the following works:

```
mount -t btrfs -o defaults,subvol=@,compress=lzo,ssd,noatime /dev/mapper/pi-root /root
```

Mounting works and I can see the filesystem properly.

Here's my `/etc/fstab`:

```
proc                   /proc    proc     defaults                                      0    0
/dev/mmcblk0p1         /boot    vfat     defaults                                      0    2
/dev/mapper/pi-root    /        btrfs    defaults,subvol=@,compress=lzo,ssd,noatime    0    1
```

Here's my `/etc/crypttab`:

```
picrypt /dev/mmcblk0p2 none luks
```

Here's my kernel command line:

```
dwc_otg.fiq_fix_enable=1 console=tty1 console=tty1 root=/dev/mapper/pi-root cryptopts=target=picrypt,source=/dev/mmcblk0p2,lvm=pi rootfstype=btrfs rootwait rootdelay=5 ro rootflags=noload,subvol=@
```

I've made sure that initramfs.gz is up to date.

Again, to reiterate, here's my setup:

- SD Card

  - Boot VFAT FS
  - LUKS Encrypted FS (`picrypt`)
  - LVM Logical Volume (`/dev/mapper/pi-root`)

    - BTRFS Filesystem
    - BTRFS Subvolume (`subvol=@`)

I have a fairly identical setup as this on my main laptop, which works fine.

During Boot, here's what happens and then what fails:

1. Decrypt LUKS Volume `picrypt`: Works
2. Open Volume Group `pi` and LV `root`: Works
3. Try mounting LV `root` via fstab: Fails with `Invalid argument`.

Busybox also seems to fail with not being able to access the tty, but that's irrelevant to the problem.

How can I debug what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by this parameter in my kernel line:

```
rootflags=noload,subvol=@
```

This parameter's value is passed directly to `mount` as filesystem options for mounting the root filesystem. By inserting debugging statements into `/scripts/local` (generated from `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local`), I was able to determine what went wrong with the mount parameters and was able to then fix my boot command line.